# Translate inline Store View Issues

Tags: magento2, store-view, inline-translations

Got a English and Dutch Store View

When I do Translate Inline for example for the Dutch Store View he also use that Translation for the English Store View and the other way around.

Someone an idea what that can be?

Answer (score 1):

As you already know how to translate inline, I will answer only to make these changes store-wise.

When you translate inline, you may have seen a checkbox "**Store View Specific**". You just have to check that checkbox before submitting translation.

Please check attached screenshot for reference.
[image: Translate Inline with store specific translations]

When you check this checkbox, Magento will translate for current store view only.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed it makes a lot of sense I didn't knew or thought about!

Comment: @alain-stout, can you upvote if it helped? :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable store code in the URL. Magento allows you to add a store code of your store view to the URL. For instance, if your Dutch store view has a code dutch, then Magento will automatically load a correct store. *domain.com/dutch* will load a Dutch version of your website.

Comment: Thanks Amrit, I know, I have that but when I do that and after magento setup upgrade, he uses the translation also for the English Store View, so that is very confusing, Hope someone knows why this is